# Creating a new local repository with JGit fails "with Bare Repository has neither a working tree..."

Tags: java, jgit

I am attempting to use JGit to create a local non-bare repository. I create the directory, then create a `Repository` object for that directory, then I use `repository.create()`. My research here shows that this is supposed to create a local non-bare repository. However, the line `repository.create()` throws an exception

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoWorkTreeException: Bare Repository has neither a working tree, nor an index.
```

This would be the message that I would expect if I had created or referenced a bare repository, and then tried to add files to it. However, this error appears on the line that creates the repository, and I am very clearly making a non-bare repository. The documentation of the create method is: "Create a new Git repository. Repository with working tree is created using this method."

I have verified that the directory is created successfully.

What is going on here?

```java
File repositoryPath = "test.git";
Repository repository = new FileRepository(repositoryPath);
repository.create(false); // This line throws the error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the documentation and `FileRepository` (meanwhile?) belongs to an internal package and access is discouraged.

You can use the `InitCommand` to create repositories like so

```
Git.init().setDirectory( directory ).call()
```

This creates a non-bare repository by default where `directory` is the working directory and `directory/.git` holds the Git object database.

For the sake of completeness: If you call the `InitCommand` with `setBare( true )`, a bare repository will be created with its object database located in `directory`.

Comment: That was an amazing find. This is exactly right. It seems that the tutorials and documentation that I was reading predated their new, more intuitive interface. Also, thank you for showing me how to improve my question formatting. accepted +1